# Hand gesture recognition (PCA) - Python

Tags: python, numpy, gesture-recognition, pca

I am trying to make hand gesture recognition by Principal Component Analysis (PCA) using python. I am following the steps in this tutorial: http://onionesquereality.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/face-recognition-using-eigenfaces-and-distance-classifiers-a-tutorial/

Here is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import glob
import numpy.linalg as linalg


#Step 1: put training images into a 2D array
filenames = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\Karim\\Desktop\\Training & Test images\\New folder\\Training/*.png')
filenames.sort()
img = [Image.open(fn).convert('L').resize((90, 90)) for fn in filenames]
images = np.asarray([np.array(im).flatten() for im in img])


#Step 2: find the mean image and the mean-shifted input images
mean_image = images.mean(axis=0)
shifted_images = images - mean_image


#Step 3: Covariance
c = np.asmatrix(shifted_images) * np.asmatrix(shifted_images.T)


#Step 4: Sorted eigenvalues and eigenvectors
eigenvalues,eigenvectors = linalg.eig(c)
idx = np.argsort(-eigenvalues)
eigenvalues = eigenvalues[idx]
eigenvectors = eigenvectors[:, idx]


#Step 6: Finding weights
w = eigenvectors.T * np.asmatrix(shifted_images)  
w = np.asarray(w)


#Step 7: Input (Test) image
input_image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Karim\\Desktop\\Training & Test images\\New folder\\Test\\31.png').convert('L').resize((90, 90))
input_image = np.asarray(input_image).flatten()


#Step 8: get the normalized image, covariance, eigenvalues and eigenvectors for input image
shifted_in = input_image - mean_image
c = np.cov(input_image)
cmat = c.reshape(1,1)
eigenvalues_in, eigenvectors_in = linalg.eig(cmat)


#Step 9: Fing weights of input image
w_in = eigenvectors_in.T * np.asmatrix(shifted_in) 
w_in = np.asarray(w_in)


#Step 10: Euclidean distance
df = np.asarray(w - w_in)                # the difference between the images
dst = np.sqrt(np.sum(df**2, axis=1))     # their euclidean distances
idx = np.argmin(dst)                     # index of the smallest value in 'dst' which should be equal to index of the most simillar image in 'images'
print idx
```

The detected image should be the nearest from the training images to the test image, but the result is a completely different one, although for each test image there are 10 similar images in the training image.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Why not use `np.cov(shifted_images)` in Step 3?

Answer (score 2):

PCA on raw image bitmaps is a poor algorithm for face recognition.  To put it bluntly, don't expect it to actually work using real images of people's faces.  It's useful as a learning tool, but that's about it.

Try testing your algorithm with extremely simple images -- think white images with black shapes in different places.  PCA should be able to do that well.  If it works on those, congrats, you wrote it correctly.  Then move up to a more sophisticated algorithm.

Or download a standard academic dataset of face images that has been shown in research to work with PCA.  Small issues like alignment and color are critical with such a simple algorithm.

Comment: I am using it for hand gesture recognition and I am getting wrong results

Comment: At least use LDA instead of PCA.  It has the exact same inputs and outputs but provides better classifications.

Comment: do you suggest a certain tutorial for LDA as I have no idea about it?

Comment: You're trying to solve a very hard problem.  You're going to need a lot more than simple tutorials.  I recommend taking this excellent class on machine learning: https://www.coursera.org/course/ml